# Showing that the Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G \subset SL(V)$ is semisimple and irreducible on $V$.

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

*Let $G \subset SL(V)$ be a connected algebraic group, acting irreducible on $V$, where $V$ is a complex vectorspace of dimension $n$*

---

**I want to show that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ is semisimple and acts irreducible on $V$.**

---

Below is the full answer to this problem. Thanks goes to *Callum* and *Bart Michels* for their hints, that greatly helped to getting this solution.

**Irreducibility:**
We have $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{sl}(V)$ a Lie subalgebra. Now note, that by assumption $G$ acts irreducible on $V$ via an representation say $\Phi$. Let $\phi$ be the associated representation for $\mathfrak{g}$. To show: $\Phi$ irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ $\phi$ irreducible:
So if we have a subspace of $V$, invariant
under the action of every $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, it is invariant under $\phi(X)^n$ for all $n$, since $V$ is finite-dimensional. Hence it must be invariant under $exp(\phi(X))$. Using that, if $G$ is a connected Lie group, it is generated by exponentials of elements of $\mathfrak{g}$, we get one implication.  Conversely, if a subspace is invariant under $G$, it must be invariant under each $\Phi(exp(hX))$ and hence also under the limit
$$lim_{h \to 0}\left(
\frac{\Phi(exp (hX)) − \Phi(I)}{h}\right)
= \phi(X).$$

**Semi-simplicity:**
To show, that $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, we need to prove that the center of $\mathfrak{g}$ is trivial. That is $$\mathfrak{z}(\mathfrak{g})=\{x \in \mathfrak{g}\mid[x,s]=0 ,\forall s \in \mathfrak{g}\}.$$ Since we consider a Lie-subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$, we have $[x,s]=xs-sx$. Now, by the irreducibility of the representation together with Schur´s lemma, we have that all elements in the center are multiples of the identity matrix. But since $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{sl}(V)$, and hence the traces need to be zero, we conclude that the center is trivial.

**Edit:**
Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be an abelian ideal and $V = \oplus_{\lambda \in\Lambda} V_{\lambda}$ the decomposition of $V$ into joint eigenspaces
$$V_{\lambda} = \{v \in V : \forall X \in \mathfrak{h}, (X - \lambda(X))v=0\}.$$
First we show, that forall $\lambda$ we have that $V_{\lambda}$ is $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant. Let $v \in V_{\lambda}$, $X \in \mathfrak{h}$ then for any $Y \in \mathfrak{g}$ we note by the comment below
$$(X - \lambda(X))Yv = [X,Y]v -\lambda(X)Yv + YXv = [X,Y]v$$
as $v \in V_{\lambda}$. Observe that $[X,Y] \in \mathfrak{h}$ and so $[X,Y]v \in V_{\lambda}$, so we have
$$(X - \lambda(X))^2Yv = (X - \lambda(X))[X,Y]v=0.$$

Recall that $X \in End(V)$ is said to be diagonalizable, if $V$ has a basis of eigenvectors for $X$. But this is equivalent to our decomposition $V = \oplus_{\lambda \in\Lambda} V_{\lambda}$.
So $X$ is diagonalizeable. Then, since the generalized eigenspaces coincide with the normal eigenspaces, this imples $Yv \in V_{\lambda}$.

Since by the first part (hopefully), $\mathfrak{g}$ acts irreducible on $V$, there can only be trivial $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant subspaces. So with the decomposition above we conclude $V = V_{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda \in \Lambda$. Hence $\forall v \in V, \forall X \in \mathfrak{h}: (X - \lambda(X))v=0$, i.e. $\forall v \in V, h \in \mathfrak{h}: Xv=\lambda(X) v$. So $\mathfrak{h}$ acts by scalars on $V$. But then again, the elements of $\mathfrak{h}$ being scalar multiples of the identity map, contradicts $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{sl}(V)$ as the traces need to be $0$. So $\mathfrak{h}=0$.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Ok, i will edit the second one out and ask seperately.

Comment: Hint: $SL(V)$ acts transitively on $V\setminus\{0\}$ So, a fortiori, it acts irreducibly

Comment: In fact since you want to look at the Lie algebra action you can instead use that $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$ acts transitively on $V$

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Well, i tried applying your hint.

Comment: @Callum So, does this proof work?

Comment: Sorry, looking at it again I thought you were asking about $G = SL(V)$ rather than $G \subset SL(V)$ so my hint is a bit lacking. Instead the easiest way that occurs to me is showing that if there exists an invariant subspace under the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ then that subspace is also invariant under the action of $G$.

Comment: No problem, im thankful for any help. So, i tried this new hint for the irreducibility. Then how about the semi-simplicity, is this idea i had there working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only shown that the center is trivial. That is not sufficient to conclude that $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple.

What is sufficient is that $\mathfrak g$ has no abelian ideal. So suppose $\mathfrak h$ is an abelian ideal.

Hint 1:

> Decompose $V$ as a direct sum of joint eigenspaces for $\mathfrak h$: For $\lambda \in \mathfrak h^*$, define $$V_\lambda = \{ v \in V : \forall X \in \mathfrak h, (X - \lambda(X))v = 0\} \,.$$

Hint 2:

> Show that the resulting decomposition of $V$ is invariant by $\mathfrak g$.

Conclude that $\mathfrak h$ acts by scalars and therefore $\mathfrak h = 0$.

Comment: Thank´s for the answer. I tried to prove the semi-simplicity with your idea. Is this Ok?

Comment: It does not make sense to write $\lambda(XY)$, because $XY \notin \mathfrak h$ in general. You need to use commutation relations to prove that the decomposition is invariant: $(X - \lambda(X))Y v = [X,Y] v - \lambda(X) Yv + YX v = [X,Y] v \in V_\lambda$. Now show that $(X - \lambda(X))Y v = 0$.

Comment: The other problem is at the end when you conclude that $\mathfrak h = 0$: you've only shown that $[\mathfrak g,  \mathfrak h] = 0$. Instead, you should do this as you did in your proof for the center, using that elements of $\mathfrak g$ have trace $0$.

Comment: Second try, and thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Careful, $Y \notin \mathfrak h$ so you cannot say that $[X,Y]=[Y,X]$. Instead, observe that $[X,Y] \in \mathfrak h$ so that $[X,Y]v \in V_\lambda$. Therefore $(X - \lambda(X))^2 Yv = (X - \lambda(X))[X,Y]v = 0$. Now, you need to show that also $(X - \lambda(X)) Yv = 0$, without the square. (Hint: decompose $Yv$ in the direct sum decomposition, or use the general fact that for a diagonalizable operator, eigenspaces and generalized eigenspaces coincide.)

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe this time it works.

Comment: Great, now I agree!